# How to put text in front of a greasepencil object?

Tags: mesh, grease-pencil, text-object

I am working on a 2D animation, that will have lots of text boxes for the audience to read. I didn't want to be inconsistent with the text, and there will be a lot of text, so to streamline the process I decided to use Blender's text features. However, the text will not render. I've looked through several guides, and none of them go into using text objects alongside greasepencil. If I remove the greasepencil object, and then render, the text will render. However, I need both the text and the greasepencil to be together in the same frame. I've made sure that the text objects are very far in front of the greasepencil object, and don't overlap. I've extruded all the text objects to .01 m, thinking that thickness might be an issue. All of the text objects have been converted into meshes, and they're either red or white in color. Again, they render fine if I get rid of the greasepencil background, but they're completely hidden by the greasepencil art if I put it back in, which doesn't make sense because the greasepencil is very far behind the text objects. Thank you for any help or suggestions!

Comment: Hmm. That’s odd. I would search for “in front” settings in the Properties editor with the GP object selected. Will try this setup out myself if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid any undesired glitch, use a little of compositing: create 3 collections, one for GP objects, one for Text meshes and one for camera, lights and other scene stuff.

Create a new view Layer: I named mines GP Layer and Text layer.
In the GP Layer turn off the text collection.
In the text Layer turn off the GP collection.

In the compositor window create this simple node setup, set the rendering film as transparent, make sure that the GP objects have a proper background and you're good to go.

[image]

Comment: Hey this works! Thanks for your help, I'm a bit new to blender and I've never used the compositing tab before. I think I can work through any future problems now too!

Answer (score 0):

You can render the gb project without the text, then render the text only but with a transparent background

Then combine them in Blender video editing .